# MultiLevel GroupBy on a single column of ultragrid

Tags: winforms, infragistics

I'm using Infragistics ultragrid with only one band. In this band there is a string column with xx.xx.xxxx values. The column can have xx or xx.xx or xx.xx.xxxx value. I want to programatically groupby so the result will be hierarchy based. Have in mind that its not possible to change the datasource (or add columns).
as an example

```
90
90.00
90.00.0098
90.00.0099
99
99.00
99.00.0012
99.01
99.01.0013
```

and i want to groupby first on the 2 first chars (1st Level), then on the first 5 chars (2nd Level) etc

```
+90
 +90.00
   90.00.98
   90.00.99
+99
 +99.00
   99.00.0012
 +99.01
   99.01.0013
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add columns to the grid to group by them.  This can be done either by added them to the datasource the the grid is bound to or by adding unbound columns to the grid and setting the values appropriately.

Comment: Thanks but as i said before its not possible to add columns (visible). Is it possible to groupby hidden columns?

Comment: By default when the columns are grouped they will not be visible in the grid.  If you wanted them to show then you would need to set the GroupByColumnsHidden property: http://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics4.win.ultrawingrid.v16.2~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultragridoverride~groupbycolumnshidden